# Xpath Python web scraping

Tags: python, forms, xpath, web, screen-scraping

This is my code. I am trying to print Business Name and it works 
But always has null value while printing Business adress.

```
from lxml import html
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup



page = requests.get('https://appext20.dos.ny.gov/lcns_public/bus_name_inq_frm?p_record_id=160001624')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
Business_Name=tree.xpath("/html/body/center[2]/table/tr[11]/td/text()")
print(Business_Name)
Business_address=tree.xpath("/html/body/center[2]/table/tr[16]/td/text()")
print(Business_address)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [How to ask a smart question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18584/how-to-ask-a-smart-question) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
driver.get('https://appext20.dos.ny.gov/lcns_public/bus_name_inq_frm?p_record_id=160001624')
table_element = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('table[summary="for layout only"]>tbody')
business_address = table_element[0].find_element_by_css_selector('tr:nth-last-child(11)>td')
```

print(business_address.text)

The reason why your code is not working is because there is no continuation to tr, so for business address, read from the bottom

Comment: I am trying to switch windows while scraping a web page that has modal window. I have tried find_element_by_link, by css selector but selenium is not able to identify the modal window. Any idea on that ? Thanks

Comment: try this............ driver.switchTo().activeElement()  or driver.switchTo().frame("ModelTitle");

Comment: wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 50)
driver.switch_to().activeElement() 
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#ctl00_MainContentPlaceHolder_ucLicenseLookup_gvSearchResults_ctl03_HyperLinkDetail').click()
info = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.modal-content').text - This is my code. It says driver has no attribute switch_to. I have tried 1)  driver.switchTo().activeElement()  2)  driver.switch_to.activeElement()  3)  driver.switchTo.activeElement() . Please let me know

Comment: AttributeError: 'SwitchTo' object has no attribute 'activeElement'

Comment: see this http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.switch_to_active_element

Comment: The doc is helpful. Thanks